# Why is List<T>.IndexOf(T) returning -1 on object that exists?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, collections

I have a foreach looping through a List of objects in an ASP.NET MVC/Razor project. I'm trying to use to index of the current object to determine if there is another object in the list.

Every time through the loop, I'm getting -1 as the value returned from Model.TodaySoups.IndexOf(soup) in the following code:

```
@foreach(MenuItem soup in Model.TodaysSoups)
{
    int i = Model.TodaysSoups.IndexOf(soup); 
    string comma = i < Model.TodaysSoups.Count ? "," : "";
    <li class="soup">@soup.Name@comma </li>
}
```

TodaysSoups is defined as:

```
public List<MenuItem> TodaysSoups
```

I've also tried defining soup implicitly:

```
var soup in Model.TodaysSoups
```

didn't help.

As far as I know, this should work. Clearly, I mistaken. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**
Any off by one issues you can ignore, I've been staring at this for a while and just trying whatever I could think of, but, thank you for trying to help me with them. The weird part is that I'm getting -1 every time.

The MenuItem definition

```
 public class MenuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<MenuOption> Options { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    public bool IsSpecial { get; set; }

    public MenuItem()
    {
        this.IsAvailable = true;
        this.IsSpecial = false;
        this.Options = new List<MenuOption>();
    }
}
```

Worth noting:
I had originally planned on using EF, but we're using the Enterprise Library 5.0 DAAB at work, so I switched over so I could get used to using that. I then ripped out what I believed to be all references to EF in my code and config files, and there's a very real possibility that I missed something, because I'm really not familiar with it. Possible cause?

Comment: did you overloaded "equals" in the wrong way in the MenuItem class?

Comment: Does `MenuItem` have an overridden `Equals` method?

Comment: Your code does look like it ought to work. Strange. Can you post (an outline of) class MenuItem ?

Comment: `i < Model.TodaySoups.Count` is always true, since the last item has the index `Count-1`.

Comment: No, it's just a few properties at this point. None named "equals".

Comment: Issue seems to be whether you are really getting `-1` (all the time) or if that is a debugging artifact. @Codes has an explanation for not getting the right output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick fix: use a for-loop.

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.TodaySoups.Count; i++)
{
    MenuItem soup = Model.TodaySoups[i];
    // now you have 'soup' and 'i'

}
```

Comment: Thanks Henk, this produced the results I was after, so I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You iterate on `Model.TodaysSoups` but then check the index in `Model.TodaySoups`. Looks like two different collections.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, that's just a typo on my part when posting the question. Will update.